# Left Swipe in android launcher

Tags: android, swipe, android-launcher

I am working with a customized launcher application using google launcher3. What i want to achieve is, on left swipe of home screen I want to navigate to another page just like an activity. I have tried creating view pager with fragments so that on swipe i can launch another fragment. But I find few issues while implementing this. Is there any other way to implement the same ?  I have seen similar features in yahoo aviate and all. Can anyone recommend me any work around for this ?